# How to control number of messages being pushed in rabbitmq?

Tags: push-notification, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I'm working with RabbitMQ and I want to specify the number of messages to push into the queue. I've searched over the internet and didn't find anything to control the number before pushing.

I have read about prefetch count and publishing messages in batches but I don't think that they relate to my problem and I don't want to limit the queue size, I want to control the number of messages pushed to the queue.